# Running Freepascal hashing functions over Physical Disks using CreateFileW on Windows

Tags: winapi, freepascal

I use Lazarus 1.2.2 and Freepascal 2.6.4.

I have a program called QuickHash that hashes files and, when I run it on Linux, it can be used to hash physcial disks too (/dev/sdXX). However, I'd like to add the ability to the Windows version.

I gather that to access physcial devices, like disks, one has to use [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Specifically, CreateFileW.

So, the user clicks a button which scans the computer for disks and lists them in a List Box. The one the user double clicks is then parsed (ListBox.GetSelectedText) for the string '\.\PhyscialDiskX' and that is assigned to a string variable,

```
  strDiskID := getDiskID(Listbox.GetSelectedText);
```

That works fine.

I then try to create a handle to that disk :

```
    hSelectedDisk := Windows.CreateFileW(PWideChar(strDiskID), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING,  FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS, 0);
```

Based on [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;100027), specifcally "You must use both the CreateFile() FILE_SHARE_READ and FILE_SHARE_WRITE flags to gain access to the drive"  I have also tried the other two combinations below :

```
hSelectedDisk := CreateFileW(PWideChar(strDiskID), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ AND FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS, 0);

hSelectedDisk := CreateFileW(PWideChar(strDiskID), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ OR FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS, 0);
```

All three successfully assign a handle. But, the top syntax and the bottom syntax eventually generate an error (explained below). The middle option immediately returns the default initialisation hash for a zero byte file, i.e. DA39... for SHA1.

My problem is I am unable to pass that handle (which is an integer) to the SHA1File and MD5FILE functions of the Freepascal md5 and SHA1 units. They expect a filename, which has to be a string.

So, if I pass it the strDiskID ('\.\PhyscialDiskX') (which defeats the objects of assigning a handle at all) I do get disk activity and the program appears to be working.

```
strDiskHashValue := SHA1Print(SHA1File(strDiskID));
ShowMessage(strDiskHashValue);
CloseHandle(hSelectedDisk);
```

But even when run on really small disks like a 500Mb USB drive, it takes many minutes and eventually returns "Run Error 1117" which according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) means

```
"ERROR_IO_DEVICE
1117 (0x45D)
The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error."
```

However, I have tried it on several working disks and the error continues.

So, my question, ultimately, is how on earth do I pass that successfully assigned THandle to the hashing functions? (UI have also asked the question at the [Lazarus forums](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,24835.msg149900.html#msg149900) but sometimes I get answers here from members who don't see the threads there)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to pass volume handles to functions that aren't expecting volume handles. These are very special handles with quite stringent requirements on their use. Not the least of which is that you must read blocks that are sector aligned, and whose sizes are multiples of the sector size.

So the solution is for you to take charge of reading the data. Read it into a buffer, and then pass that buffer to the hashing library. This means that you'll need a hashing library that can be called repeatedly to process new data. All comprehensive hashing libraries will offer such functionality.

The share mode flags are combined with bitwise or:

```
FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE
```

I would create the handle like this:

```
hSelectedDisk := CreateFileW(PWideChar(strDiskID), FILE_READ_DATA,
  FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
```

First of all I would concentrate on reading the content of the volume. Once you can do that, hashing will be routine.

---

It seems from the comments that you are having some trouble writing the hashing code. First of all you need to allocate a buffer that is a multiple of the sector size:

```
var
  Buffer: Pointer;
....
GetMem(Buffer, BufferSize);
```

Use `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY` to find out the sector size. And take note of this text from the documentation:

> To read or write to the last few sectors of the volume, you must call DeviceIoControl and specify FSCTL_ALLOW_EXTENDED_DASD_IO. This signals the file system driver not to perform any I/O boundary checks on partition read or write calls. Instead, boundary checks are performed by the device driver.

Now that you have a buffer, you can read and hash the content.

```
var
  ctx: TSHA1Context;
  Digest: TSHA1Digest;
  BytesRead: DWORD;
....
SHA1Init(ctx);
repeat
  if not ReadFile(hSelectedDisk, Buffer^, BufferSize, BytesRead, nil) then
    // handle error, raise exception
  SHA1Update(ctx, Buffer^, BytesRead);
until BytesRead < BufferSize;
SHA1Final(ctx, Digest);
```

I've not attempted to compile or test this code. It's not meant to be complete or comprehensive. It is just intended to show you how to tackle the problem.

Comment: Hi David. I much obliged for your help. When you say "you'll need a hashing library that can be called repeatedly to process new data. All comprehensive hashing libraries will offer such functionality", if the md5 and sha1 units built into Freepascal are not one such example, do you know of one that is? I also use DCPCrypt for SHA256 & SHA512 but not sure if that offers what you refer to.

Comment: I'm not familiar with FPC hashing libraries. The point is that it is common to want to hash files that do not fit in main memory. For instance, in a 32 bit process, how would one hash an 8GB file? You cannot load it all into memory at once. So what you do is read a chunk, pass to the hasher. Read another chunk, pass to the hasher. The hasher keeps a running state of the hash. I'm sure that any good and useful hashing library will offer such an interface.

Comment: Hi David. Well the FPC hash functions can do just that. If I pass a large 20Gb file to it, it hashes it fine. I gather it reads the data in 1024 byte chunks in fact. And if I use the Linux version of my program and select a /dev/ device, it will hash the disk if run as root. But I can't do it that way for Windows because you can't pass a physcial disk to SHA1File or MD5File as a file, in Windows.

Comment: Internally the library will use a mechanism as I describe. It's unusual that the mechanism is not exposed publically. Are you sure it is not? Where can I find the source for these libraries to check?

Comment: Odly, I've never tried to find a web based version of them before for reading because I always access them via the Lazarus IDE, where they are stored at lazarus\fpc\2.6.4\source\packages\hash\src\sha1.pas and md5.pas. But I regret I cannot attach them nor point you to the SVN link. The Lazarus project is held at Sourceforge but the FPC code doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: I have those files on my machine. And it's as I thought. You need `SHA1Init`, `SHA1Update` (called repeatedly) and then `SHA1Final` to finish the job. The exact same for MD5 but with MD5xxx instead of SHA1xxx. Have a read of how `SHA1File` is implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers David. Yeah, I can see how those functions come together when working on a file. Blockread is implemented for reading untyped data into buffers. But I'm afraid my skills are not sufficiently high to work out how to integrate or hack that for use with physcial disk input. So I think I'll give up on the idea as I've spent several weeks trying. Thanks for your help with it though.

Comment: Don't give up so easily. You are very nearly there. Are you able to read in the data from the disk using `ReadFile`? Or you could even do it with a `THandleStream` if FPC has `THandleStream`. Anyway, if you can get as far as reading in the raw volume data, then hashing is not a big step. I'd gladly show you how to do the hashing.

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement David. Yes, I am able to use Readile. I use it like this : if not Readfile(hSelectedDisk, RawMBR[0], SizeOf(RawMBR), BytesRead, nil) then RaiseLastError; I can then parse out the RawMBR array as hex to a memo field. If you go to my linked Lazarus forum thread http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,24835.msg149900.html#msg149900),  my demo project is attached - only about 3 small functions (you need to be a logged in member to access the download).I just need to work out how to pass the same data to SHA1File etc for every sector of the disk.

Comment: I'll add some code to the answer over the weekend. When I get a chance.

Comment: DavidIf it helps you help me, I have uploaded my shell project that does everything except the actual hash step to my Google Drive. All you would need do is download it, perhaps adjust the CreateFile call as you state in your first answer, and then you could edit for the hash. If you do have time to do so, I'd appreciate good comments so I can understand how you do it. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1celo-GPMLHdTV1SmpleFU1dmM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I wrote you some outline code. I've done all I can now, I think.

Comment: David, thankyou! I have now done it thanks to your advice! Using a combination of FileSeek, FileRead, SHA1Init, SHA1Update and SHA1Final, I now loop through in 4Kb blocks. I also utilise IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO and IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY Windows API calls. Basically, once my repeat until gets to the exact size in bytes of the disk, it stops. Inside the reapt loop it just reads 4Kb, SHA1Update, increments, and so on. Seems to work quite well!. So thanks again.